# I''m getting a NullPointerException while trying to pass an intent via onFinish()

Tags: android, android-intent

What I'm trying to do is pass values through an intent using the onFinish() method from the CountDownTimer Class. The flow of intent is like this. My MyCountDownTimer Class holds the method that will pass the intent/values. It looks like this. I commented where the NullPointerException came in. This is a snippet from my Retry Activity.

```
 /*
  *  Retry Activity
  */

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()== R.id.retry){

            Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
            whichTest = extras1.getInt("whichTest"); //NullPointerException


            if (whichTest == 1){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Retry.this, Test1.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }

            if (whichTest == 2){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Retry.this, Test2.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
```

This is the Activity that utilizes the method. It's called Test1

```
/*
  *  Test1 Activity
  */

//Timer

    textCounter = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCounter));


    myCountDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(textCounter, 5000, 1000);
    myCountDownTimer.start();
   textCounter.setText("");
    myCountDownTimer.onTick(5000);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {



            if (textCounter==null){

                myCountDownTimer.onFinish();

    }
```

This snippet is from the MyCountDownTimer Class

```
/*
  *  MyCountDownTimer
  */
 @Override
    public void onFinish() {


        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);

           if (textCounter.getContext().equals(Test1.class)){
               whichTest = 1;
               retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
           }
        if (textCounter.getContext().equals(Test2.class)){
            whichTest = 2;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }
        textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);



}
```

If you would like to see a more full version, go here https://gist.github.com/asonofman

Here is the logcat

```
03-16 12:32:39.379    4625-4625/com.dose.apps.brainnoodles E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dose.apps.brainnoodles.Retry.onClick(Retry.java:40)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Done. In the very first block of code of posted. You will see where the NullPointerException is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this:

```
textCounter.getContext().equals(Test1.class)
```

will always return `false`. Any chance you're looking for:

```
textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test1
```

Following from this, there will be no extras added to your intent, so:

```
Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
```

`extras1` will be `null`

Comment: I typed what you said. It said textCounter.getContext() instanceof Test1.class is always false

Comment: There was a typo in my answer, there shouldn't have been a `.class`